# Compiling stanford nlp, FileNotFound for manifest file

Tags: java, nlp, javac, stanford-nlp

I have very limited knowledge in Java and I am trying to recompile stanford nlp. I have extracted the source and modified what I wanted.
According to the compiling instructions, running

```
ant
cd classes
jar -cfm ../stanford-corenlp.jar ../META-INF/MANIFEST.MF edu
```

Should recompile the sources into the executable stanford-corenlp.jar.
However, I get FileNotFound exception for MANIFEST.MF.
Should I provide this file as input for compilation? If yes, what is this file and where can find the correct version of it for compilation?

Answer (score 2):

Does `ant jar` work for you? The ant build.xml file at the root of the project should have a target that creates a jar file for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me:

```
ant all
cd classes
jar -cfm ../stanford-corenlp.jar ../src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF edu
```